# Closure compiler command line for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-compiler

I found on the Internet severals forum about importation of jquery in compiled file

> https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?csw=1
>
> [Using Google Closure compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226298/using-google-closure-compiler)
>
> [Is it possible to use Closure Compiler ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017469/is-it-possible-to-use-closure-compiler-advanced-optimizations-with-jquery/10673408#10673408)

They talk about Externs but when I compile my code I got an error :

> $ is not defined

I tried this commands :

> java -jar compiler.jar --js js/test.js js/test.js --js_output_file min-js/app.min.js --externs jquery-3.3.externs.js --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
>
> java -jar compiler.jar --js js/test.js js/test.js --js_output_file min-js/app.min.js --externs https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS

test.js is a simple code that i want to compresss :

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    var val = 0;

    //document.querySelector( ".button" ).addEventListener( "click", upButton );
    $( ".button" ).on( "click", upButton );

    function upButton() {

        val++;
        document.querySelector( ".show" ).innerText = val;

    }

} )
```

**Test JakeParis**

File test.js

```
jQuery( function($) {

    var val = 0;

    //document.querySelector( ".button" ).addEventListener( "click", upButton );
    $( ".button" ).on( "click", upButton );

    function upButton() {

        val++;
        document.querySelector( ".show" ).innerText = val;

    }

} )
```

Command

> java -jar compiler.jar --js js/test.js --js_output_file min-js/app.min.js --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --externs js/jquery.js

Error
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6CA5.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the `$` variable not being available in the global scope. Oftentimes, the jQuery library is available globally as `jQuery` instead of `$`. Perhaps, you should use this instead:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
```

which can also be shortened to

```
jQuery( function($) {
```

Then everything inside that code block can use the `$` as a reference to jQuery.

Comment: i try this and i tell you in a few minutes thank you.

Comment: It's not working I got an error please llok at the post I updated it